# Illegal Escape Character "\"

Tags: java, string, escaping, char

I want to get the name at the end of a link so I did that

```
if( invName.substring(j,k).equals("\")){
                                 copyf=invName.substring(0,j);}
```

Eclipse said String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

How can I compare String with this char `\` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The character '\' is a special character and needs to be escaped when used as part of a String, e.g., "\".  Here is an example of a string comparison using the '\' character:

```
if (invName.substring(j,k).equals("\\")) {...}
```

You can also perform direct character comparisons using logic similar to the following:

```
if (invName.charAt(j) == '\\') {...}
```

Comment: thaaanks sir if (invName.substring(j,k).equals("\\")) {...} thats work

Comment: Also when the String is a Regex escaping a special char with ``\``. For the compiler it is at first a String. So for a dot use `"\\."`.

Answer (score 14):

Use `"\\"` to escape the \ character.

Comment: what if i need to update json format like '{"URL":"https:\/\/test.myscripts.com\/\/api\/\/Orders\/\/Submit"}'

Answer (score 0):

I think ("\") may be causing the problem because \ is the escape character. change it to ("\\")

Answer (score 0):

do two \'s

"\\"

it's because it's an escape character

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\\
```

That's ok, for example:

```
if (invName.substring(j,k).equals("\\")) {
    copyf=invName.substring(0,j);
}
```