# Android edit/insert into string

Tags: android, string, insert, edit

I was wondering how I could programmatically edit strings in android. I am displaying strings from my device to my website, and the apostrophes ruin the PHP output. so in order to fix this, I needed to add character breaks, ie: the backslash '\'.

For example, if I have this string: I love filiberto's! 
I need android to edit it to: I love filiberto\'s!

However, each string is going to be different, and there will also be other characters that I have to escape from . How can I do this?

I was wondering how I could programmatically edit strings in android. I am displaying strings from my device to my website, and the apostrophes ruin the PHP output. so in order to fix this, I needed to add character breaks, ie: the backslash '\'.

This is what I have so far, thanks to ANJ for base code...:

```
if(title.contains("'")) {
    int i;
    int len = title.length();
    char[] temp = new char[len + 1]; //plus one because gotta add new
    int k = title.indexOf("'"); //location of apostrophe 
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) { //all the letters before the apostrophe
        temp[i] = title.charAt(i); //assign letters to array based on index
    }
    temp[k] = 'L';  // the L is for testing purposes
    for (i = k+1; i == len; i++) { //all the letters after apostrophe, to end
        temp[i] = title.charAt(i); //finish the original string, same array
    }
    title = temp.toString(); //output array to string (?)
    Log.d("this is", title); //outputs gibberish
}
```

Which outputs random characters.. not even similar to my starting string. Does anyone know what could be causing this? For example, the string "Lol'ok" turns into >> "%5BC%4042ed0380"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are storing the string somewhere. Lets say the string is: str.
You can use a temporary array to add the '/'. For a single string:

```
    int len = str.length();
    char [] temp = new char[len+1];   //Temporary Array
    int k = str.indexOf("'"), i;      //Finding index of "'"
    for(i=0; i<k-1; i++) 
    {
     temp[i] = str.charAt(i);        //Copying the string before '
    }
    temp[k] = '/';                   //Placing "/" before '
    for(i=k; j<len; j++)
    {
        temp[i+1] = str.charAt(i);     //Copying rest of the string
    }
    String newstr = temp.toString();    //Converting array to string
```

You can use the same for multiple strings. Just make it as a function and call it whenever you want.

Comment: I am currently trying to implement this now, however I have a problem. I'm assuming there's a quick fix; I just don't know it. I need to have it be a backslack, \, not a forward slash. But the backslash prevents the end quote. How can I fix this? Also, running this outputs my text to random, like for example: %5BC%4042e5a9b8...Which I don't get. Is this because it's going from a string, to an array, back to a string? Do I have to save the enumerations to a new string, or does Android handle that? Also, is j just a new integer, or should it be replaced with I, to pick up where it left off?

Comment: Sorry j was a mistake. It should be I only.

Comment: For the backslash, look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character. I am unable to get your  3rd question though. Are u saying %5BC%4042e5a9b8 is your original string and you are unable to convert it?

Comment: for example, the string "I'm" becomes "[C@42ebf1c0"

Comment: I don't know why its not working for you. It works fine in my studio. One thing is change "temp.toString();" to "Arrays.toString(temp);". Try it this might work.

Answer (score 0):

The String API has a number of API calls that could help, for example [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). But...

> apostrophes ruin the PHP output

Then fix the PHP code rather than require "clean" input. Best option would be to select a well supported transport format (say JSON or XML) and let the Json API on each end handle escape code.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with JSON, I'm using MySQL PDO and it was such a struggle getting to where I am now that I think it would just be easier to clean up the input, verses the output