# Kotlin - Form feed character - Illegal escape: '\f'

Tags: escaping, kotlin, string-literals

`Kotlin` does not support the escape `"\f"` (Form Feed Character). So what is the proper way port `"\f"` from `java` to `Kotlin`?

Java:

```
String str = "\f"; // OK
```

Kotlin:

```
var str = "\f"  // Illegal escape: '\f'
```

Anyway, that looked like a bug to me because Kotlin and java should work well together.

Comment: Please vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21407 :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character from this source: // is enough

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character `// is enough`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use unicode escape `\u000C`. [Kotlin doesn't support the `\f` escape.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/characters.html) It isn't very widely used. - in fact I didn't realize that there is `\f` in Java until seeing your question.

I made a table on the Java and kotlin escape sequence:

```
Escape type|kotlin |java
\uXXXX      yes     yes
\XXX        no      yes         // this is Java octal escape.
\t          yes     yes
\b          yes     yes
\n          yes     yes
\r          yes     yes
\f          no      yes
\'          yes     yes
\"          yes     yes
\\          yes     yes
\$          yes     no          // Java just uses $
```

(Kotlin needs the escaped $ because [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) use $.)