# Need java regex pattern to determine the range after 1 alphabet

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to prevent an incorrect entry - 'A+ 9 digits'. Example `a1234567`, `a12345678`, `a123456789` are valid entries.

I tried: `[A]{1} + (([0-9]{7}$ | [0-9]{8}$ | [0-9]{9}$))`. It's working fine but is there any way to check this limit, like a+7,8,9 digits?

I have tried `[A]{1} + (\d{7}|\d{8}|\d{9})$`

But as in my project they are using `java.util.regex.pattern.compile` hence it's giving me an error message.

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: Try: `^[Aa]\d{7,9}$`

Comment: Must the digits increase from left to right?

Comment: *" ...hence it's giving me an error message."* - What was the error message?

Comment: Exception is  java illegal escape character \

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal Escape Character "\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character)

Comment: @Janezkuhar no it can be anything for example A12345678 or A1562378 or A100000000

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in a Java regular expression. So, for example, `\d` becomes `\\d`.

Answer (score 0):

About the patterns that you tried:

- The space has meaning in a regex
- To match an `A` you don't have to use the square brackets and `{1}`
- If you want to use `\d` you have to double escape the backslash like `\\d`

You can shorten your initial regex to

```
^[aA][0-9]{7,9}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[aA]` Match either `A` or `a`
- `[0-9]{7,9}` Match 7-9 times a digit 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ztl7rB/1)