# illegal escape character from String.format()

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error, string-formatting

#### Edit:

I am getting "error: illegal escape character" when I try to compile my Java program.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String output = String.format("%7d\%7d\%5d\t%%5s\t%s", 1299.97, 465.64, 1963, "00694", "ATLAS CENTAUR 2");
}
```

Expected output:

```
 1299.97      465.64    1963      00694        ATLAS CENTAUR 2
```

Output from javac:

```
Main.java:6: error: illegal escape character
        String output = String.format("%7d\%7d\%5d\t%%5s\t%s", 1299.97, 465.64, 1963, "00694", "ATLAS CENTAUR 2");
                                           ^
Main.java:6: error: illegal escape character
        String output = String.format("%7d\%7d\%5d\t%%5s\t%s", 1299.97, 465.64, 1963, "00694", "ATLAS CENTAUR 2");
                                               ^
2 errors
```

How do I fix this?

#### Original question, can be ignored:

[error at line 44 and I don't know how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yknx.png)

```
Hi I am new to java programming. I want to write a java program to print out the satilites from a website. Error at line 44 and I don't know how to fix it. I'm not sure if I'm using the .format right. Can I please have some help?

This is the assignment:
```

Assignment 3 is:

Write 3 functions:

```
apogee which takes 2 parameters, mean motion and eccentricity and returns the apogee in kilometers.

perigee which takes 2 parameters, mean motion and eccentricity and returns the perigee in kilometers.

launch year yyyy which takes an integer parameter, the 2 digit launch year, and returns an integer, the 4 digit launch year.

    hint: use the date for the 1st ever artificial satellite launch to write a function that will work until 2057
```

Don't forget about the "assumed decimal point" for the eccentricity. (Use String concatenation to pre-pend a leading "0." to the extracted substring before converting it to double).

It should look like this :

```
 1299.97      465.64    1963      00694        ATLAS CENTAUR 2         
  813.27      765.76    1964      00733        THOR AGENA D R/B        
  753.32      648.28    1964      00877        SL-3 R/B                
  799.01      704.45    1967      02802        SL-8 R/B                
  616.16      574.02    1968      03230        SL-8 R/B                
  .....................................................
```

Comment: Three issues: you've put text in a code block making it hard to read, and tagged javascript when this is not javascript, and linked a picture of code, rather than put code in the question

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Everywhere you have ``\%`` in your format string should be ``\\%`` (assuming you want an actual ``\`` in your output).

Comment: I tried to post it in the text box but it didn't work

Comment: I tried to put it in the questions but it didn't work. I also tried the \\% but it didn't work I still got an error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For users here to consider your issue you need to paste your program, or better yet, a [mre], into the question proper and format it as code (there’s a button for that). And paste the error output in the same way (format as code too to preserve line breaks). And point out which line is line 44 (the `System.out.println()` line).

Comment: Take into account that most readers here are not following your link to the image of your IDE. And also that the first thing many readers will want to do is either paste the error message into their search engine, which they canot do from an image, or run the program themselves, which they canot do from an image either.

Comment: Since you’re new here, in an attempt to show you a question format we generally like I have added a [mre] showing your problem to your question. I would really have preferred to delete the original text and link since I don’t think they contribute anything once we have the MRE; but deleting your text entirely would probably have been too brutal, so I compromised there. I hope you can use it as inspiration for your next Stack Overflow questions. And if you didn’t like it at all, just revert my edit.

Comment: Similar but maybe not exactly the same: [Illegal Escape Character "\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character)

Answer (score 1):

You can review the *format specifiers* on the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#conversions-heading)* class *JavaDoc*.

Real number values use *%f*.
And, integer number values use *%d*.

You can use the following, to obtain a similar output as required.

```java
"%7f %7f %5d %5s %s"
```

```
1299.970000 465.640000  1963 00694 ATLAS CENTAUR 2
```

You can specify a scale using *%.2f*, where *.2* is the scale.
And, you can add leading zeros by adding a *0* before the width.

```java
"%7.2f %7.2f %5d %5s %s"
```

```
1299.97  465.64  1963 00694 ATLAS CENTAUR 2
```

Comment: @OleV.V., no thanks man.  Take your comments elsewhere.